# How to pass variable to graphql query using graphql-request?

Tags: graphql

I'm trying to follow [graphql-request package documentation](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-request#passing-headers-in-each-request) to make a GraphQL query like so:

```
async function main() {
  const query = gql`
    {
        user(id: $userId)  {
            id
            email
            name
        }
    }
  `;
  const variables = {
    userId: '4dc70521-22bb-4396-b37a-4a927c66d43b',
  };
  const endpoint = 'https://api.mocki.io/v2/c4d7a195/graphql';
  const client = new GraphQLClient(endpoint);
  const data = await client.request(query, variables);
}
```

but when I run it I get the error:

"ClientError: Variable "$userId" is not defined."

What's the correct way of passing a variable to a query like this?